# Name for Stripe Pattern & Implementing It in PhotoShop or Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, mask, patterns

I'm looking for the name of this style of striping, as well as how I might go about implementing it as, say, a vector mask.  See below the image for additional thoughts.

[image]

Specifically, this striping appears to involve a pattern where each stripe section has a portion of negative and a portion of positive space.  How much is negative/positive from section to section appears to wax/wane proportionally such that one end of the graphic has a mostly negative space stripe and the other has a mostly positive space one.

Ultimately, I would love to figure out some way to create a selection or mask that makes each section a certain width, and alters the negative/positive space by a specified increment from stripe to stripe.  I would like to be able to create such a mask/selection pattern over a solid shape, and resize the pattern until it had the right look before applying it to the solid image and knocking out all the appropriate negative space stripes.

As of now, my best idea is to create a guides layout in PhotoShop to represent the sections, then manually create a guide within each section, moved by a certain number of pixels, then using those guides to make a big complicated selection, finally converting it to a path which can be resized.  This idea seems kind of masochistic to me.

Comment: In illustrator: Circle, gradient, 1 thick black line + 1 thin black line + [blend tool](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/blending-objects.html), object > expand, window > pathfinder - to cut out the lines from the circle shape.

Comment: @Joonas why do you need to expand?

Comment: @joojaa, you can't use pathfinder on a blended group as it is. Expanding breaks it down into just paths. Then you can use pathfinder to easily clip the lines out of the circle.

Comment: @Joonas why would you need to do that can  you not use a clipping mask

Comment: @joojaa, I felt using pathfinder was cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seemingly nearly same is presented already as a comment:

[image]

In Illustrator:

1. Draw a couple of rectangles
2. Make a blend, expand it when you are happy, ungroup, select the slices and make compound path or union.

*No need to expand the blend nor make a compound path, if you want to transfer the slices to Photoshop without clipping them to any other form in Illustrator. Only select all, copy to the clipboard and paste to Photoshop. After pasting you can select the wanted object type and you can scale before rasterizing, if you want a bitmap.*

3. Draw a circle above all. No need to have a fill, it's green only to show it clearly
4. In the pathfinder panel make an intersection
5. Insert the wanted background, rotate, insert the wanted fill (here a gradient)

You can copy and paste the result into Photoshop after step 4. You can take it as bitmap, smart object, vector shape or path:

[image]

You can use it in Photoshop like any shape. here it's a rasterized layer mask:

[image]

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting to the end. I mostly stumble around in Illustrator, so that's part of my problem. I'm not trying to create the circle itself there, but just generate the line pattern which I can somehow get to PS as a vector mask to place over whatever shape I want. I've gotten the blend made, expanded and now have acceptable lines (which I made using a thinly stroked line and thickly stroked line per the comment).  When I try to make a compound path, all the stroking disappears and I'm left with what feels like nothing but unstroked paths.

Comment: @bubbleking I inserted how to transfer the blend to Photoshop. Start with rectangles or outline the strokes before blending to get areas.